# Find CGI RPG program causing job log SQL errors

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm running Apache on the IBM i, set up for CGI calls to RPG ILE programs that use embedded SQL.

I'm getting various SQL errors in these programs (eg "Indicator variable required" and "Cursor not open"), but I can't find which programs specifically are causing these issues. There are many hundreds of programs in this system, and hitting F1 on the error messages does not specify the source program (the message is from/to 'QSQRUN2').

I can't recompile every program in debug mode, which might give more information (production system, some source issues).

Any ideas on how to get this information?

Comment: Does STRTRC with TRCTYP *DBSQL provide more information?

Comment: Though you can't recompile for debug, can you put one or more of the server jobs under debug (e.g., via STRSRVJOB)? Or start the DB monitor (STRDBMON) against one or more server jobs to see what's captured. If the errors are within procedures, the database monitor should record procedure names. Any debug or monitor would be run only temporarily to see if a joblog or monitor database logged useful info.

Comment: @user2338816 STRDBMON is exactly what I needed! `STRDBMON OUTFILE(QGPL/DBMON) JOB(*ALL/QTMHHTTP/WEBSERVER) FTRSQLCODE(*ERROR)` will list all SQL statements with errors, their text, and what program they are coming from! If you want to make an answer, I'll give it to you.

Comment: @ScottR : It won't make me richer, and I didn't know how it would work with however your processes are structured nor what command parms would be best. Too many possible variables. But I'm pleased it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2338816 gave this answer in the comments.

There is an easy way to add SQL monitoring for specific jobs.

```
STRDBMON OUTFILE(QGPL/DBMON) JOB(*ALL/QTMHHTTP/WEBSERVER) FTRSQLCODE(*NONZERO)
```

Starts a monitor that monitors all jobs (current or future) for user QTMHHTTP, job WEBSERVER, logging all statements that give a warning or error.

See [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajq%2Ft1000.htm) for details on the resulting QGPL/DBMON database file.

You can then cross reference the job number/time in the job log if you need some context.

Answer (score 1):

Where are seeing the errors?

You say "hitting F1..." do you mean hitting F10=Display Messages in Job Log; from the 7=Display message on the WRKACTJOB screen?

If so, try 5=Work With and 11=Display Call stack..

If the job's not going into MSGW, then your programs are swallowing the errors.  Either improperly without doing anything with them.  Or properly after handling the issue (and neglecting to clean up the job log) or logging the data you need somewhere.  You'll just have to find out where.

Comment: WRKACTJOB SBS(QHTTPSVR), 5=Work With, 10=Display Job Log.

Comment: These are SQL errors, and they don't produce MSGW message (which is actually a good thing). They just log a message in the job log and continue on. Call stack isn't helpful because the CGI jobs are on to the next web request by the time I see the error.

Comment: I actually wouldn't want the programs to 'clean up the job log', that would hide actual problems. I know there are problems, I just can't find the needle in the haystack as to which program is causing the errors.

Comment: What I mean is that if the errors are expected and the program is handling them; then it should clean up the job log so you aren't chasing non-issues.  Are you seeing some other evidence of a problem or are you just seeing the messages in the job log?

Comment: I repeat - I don't know what programs are causing these job log messages. I agree with your logic - but first I need to figure out what programs are causing these messages in order to make sure these are non-issues.

Comment: It seems in this case a MSGW would almost be preferred. That usually comes after an unmonitored/unhandled *ESCAPE and that's what seems not to be happening. If that was the case, a simple handler could be assigned to the message ID to log each program that saw it.

Comment: It's possible but it's a *lot* of work to add. There's at least a thousand programs, probably tens of thousands of SQL statements, written by dozens of programmers from at least 3 different vendors. And we don't have the source for half of them. :) A less intrusive way would be better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of the message in the job log, and it has a statement in the "Cause" that calls out the host variable name. In the example, it is "TCANDSBMDT". Does that help narrow it down?

```
Message ID . . . . . . :   SQL0305                                             
Date sent  . . . . . . :   08/06/12      Time sent  . . . . . . :   10:41:52   

Message . . . . :   Indicator variable required.                               

Cause . . . . . :   A FETCH, embedded SELECT, CALL, GET DESCRIPTOR, or a SET   
  or VALUES INTO statement has resulted in a null value, but an indicator      
  variable was not specified for host variable TCANDSBMDT. ...
```

Comment: Right - that particular message does list the host variable. The problem is when 100+ programs use that variable name (these aren't the best coded programs in the world).  The other errors like cursor not open don't list any information.